# How may I use CGAL in Python?

Tags: python, cgal

It seems to me that the `CGAL` documentation is not well documented. I am totally lost with how to use their packages in Python.

I have installed `CGAL-4.3` on my Windows, and I tried to do

```
In [233]: """ python 2.4"""
   .....: from CGAL.Alpha_shapes_2 import *
   .....: from CGAL.Triangulations_2 import Delaunay_triangulation_2
   .....: from CGAL.Kernel import *
   .....: from ShapeHelper import *
   .....: import numpy as np
   .....: import sys
```

**Error message** says

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-233-4807de38949d> in <module>()
      1 """ python 2.4"""
----> 2 from CGAL.Alpha_shapes_2 import *
      3 from CGAL.Triangulations_2 import Delaunay_triangulation_2
      4 from CGAL.Kernel import *
      5 from ShapeHelper import *

ImportError: No module named CGAL.Alpha_shapes_2
```

What should I do so that I can import these modules correctly?

After I can import them, it is as easy as using any other modules in python.

Comment: Have you added `cgal-python` to your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @tijko yes, strangely ImportError: No module named Kernel

Comment: No I think it is this particular package. Could you please kindly help check this out? I suspect there is something missing inside. https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/shownotes.php?release_id=3674

Comment: @tijko it would be great if you can try importing it into ur python. I think it will also not work...

Comment: What windows version are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40894/discussion-between-perfectionm1ng-and-tijko)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some [Unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to go with python scientific-extension packages that are not compatible with Windows out of the box.

There is one for CGAL-python in the link provided, a little ways down.

Comment: Works like magic! It saves a lot of trouble for Windows users (especially newbies)! :D